# complex for declaration containing scanf and printf

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int i;
main()
{
    int t;
    for ( t=4;scanf("%d",&i)-t;printf("%d\n",i))
        printf("%d--",t--);
}
```

If the inputs are 0, 1, 2, 3, the output is:

```
4--0 
3--1
2--2
```

Please explain the output of the program. I'm unable to figure out why the output is like that. How does the loop work in this program? Why isn't the printf in the for loop printed first?

Comment: Think about the different parts of a for loop and apply the statements you have here instead.

Comment: Without a prototype in scope for `printf()` and `scanf()` any output is reasonable (or the absence of output ... or a liquid diamond oozing out of the USB port).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'scanf' returns the number of items assigned. For your input, scanf returns 1 for every input (because you wanted to read one item at a time by one '%d'). The variable t started with 4. Now the condition of the 'for' for every iteration becomes: 1-4, 1-3, 1-2 and 1-1 (=0) and hence in case of '1-1' it didn't enter the loop body (because the condition result is 0, means false) and terminated the loop. Hope it explains the result of your program.

Answer (score 2):

Transform the `for` loop into an equivalent `while` loop. A `for` loop of the form

```
for (initialize; condition; increment)
{
    body;
}
```

can be equivalently written as:

```
initialize;
while (condition)
{
    body;
    increment;
}
```

Notice how the `increment` statement ends up at the bottom of the loop. It is executed *after* the loop body, right before starting the next iteration of the loop.

So your loop becomes this:

```
int i;
main()
{
    int t;
    t = 4;
    while (scanf("%d",&i) - t)
    {
        printf("%d--", t--);
        printf("%d\n", i));
    }
}
```

Does that help?

The trickiest is part is the loop condition. The loop will exit when its condition becomes 0. `scanf` returns the number of items read in, which here will be 1 for the one `%d` that is read in each time. If `scanf` returns 1 every time then the loop exits when `t` hits 1.

Comment: thanks, but why printf("%d\n", i) is after printf("%d--",t--)

Comment: @Java : Flow of execution of for loop is like... Initialization --> Condition -->Body --> increment or decrement so this is

Answer (score 0):

The third step of `for` operator is called after the loop's body is executed.

Speaking of your example, this...

```
for ( t=4;              // initialization statement
      scanf("%d",&i)-t; // check statement; if `false`, the loop is finished
      printf("%d\n",i)) // step statement, usually advances an iteration one step

  printf("%d--",t--);
```

... is walked by like this:

1. FOR initialization: assign 4 to `t`.
2. FOR check: do `scanf`, assign result (0) to `i`, check whether 1 (result of `scanf`) is equal to `t`; it's not for now.
3. FOR loop: do `printf` for postdecremented `t` (it prints `4--`)
4. FOR step: do `printf` mentioned within the `for` clause, prints `0\n`
5. FOR check: do `scanf`, assign result (1) to `i`, check whether 1 is equal to `t` (which is 3 now, as it was decremented).
6. FOR loop: do `printf` for postdecremented `t` (it prints `3--`)
7. FOR step: do `printf` mentioned within the `for` clause, prints `1\n`
8. FOR check: do `scanf`, assign result (2) to `i`, check whether 1 is equal to `t` (which is 2 now, as it was decremented).
9. FOR loop: do `printf` for postdecremented `t` (it prints `2--`).
10. FOR step: do `printf` mentioned within the `for` clause, prints `2\n`
11. FOR check: do `scanf`, assign result (3) to `i`, check whether 1 is equal to `t` (which is 1 now).
12. FOR check failed => loop is finished.